# Local html file into iframe in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe, redux

How do I make an iframe display a local html file from a React component. My problem is that when i point to my locale html file the react router picks up the request and redirect to the main page. So the iframe shows the main page instead of the static html page.

Is there a way to tell the router not to take a specific path?

Comment: I don't think react-router is causing the problem, make sure to check your server configuration... generally when using client-side routing the server is configured to serve a common static page for all routes that it doesn't recognize....

Comment: I checked and tried to intercept the call to the local html page, and it's the router that picking it up and redirecting me. So i need to make the router not pick up the call folder/file.html. I also tired with the file:/// parameter but that's not allowed by most browser by default, so that also no good.

Comment: show some code, behaviours!!

Comment: Hi @spitfire511 Did you manage to find a solution? I am having the same issue.